# Would this work for searching something in my DB?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Create Proc CargarAnuncioPorBusqueda
    @searchString varchar(max)
AS 
select * from Anuncio where titulo Like '%'+ @searchString + '%'
```

Say the user writes: "pools", would this Stored Procedure return everything that has "pools" in the "titulo"?

Thank you. :)

Comment: This may be dependent on the version of SQL Server you are using.  Can you specify the version -- 2000, 2005, 2008, other?

Comment: Depending on where your @searchString variable comes from, you may be leaving yourself open to SQL injection.  Just something to think about; stored procs are not a magic bullet against SQL injection.

Comment: Didn't I already correct your bad 'mssql' tag once this morning?

Comment: @rmeador: it's not vulnerable to injection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. It would return "spools", "poolside", "pools", etc.

Comment: Great! All I needed to know. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Yes that's the correct use of the like operator.

You can also do a logical Starts With like this:

```
like @searchterm + '%'
```

and Ends With like this:

```
like '%' + @searchterm
```

Comment: Your startswith and endswith are backwards.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a very fast search though.

Comment: How is this a slow search? I'm new to SQL in general. ;)

Comment: It's not sargable (that means it can't use indexes).

Comment: it will look at every row in the table, that means that as data increases it will get slower and slower